# how to get whatsapp working on ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, software-installation

I don't have an android phone.please help me to acess whatsapp on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Currently whatsapp only supports mobile platforms. The possible solution is to run whatsapp using an android emulator.

Bluestacks is a good choice but its not available on Linux. You could try installing [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) which is available for all platforms viz Linux, Windows and Mac.

For detailed instructions to get whatsapp running under Linux visit this [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-run-whatsapp-in-ubuntu-using-genymotion-bluestacks-more/).